# simple Apache2mod_proxy a backend server

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-proxy, git

Hello I'm trying to figure out mod_proxy in apache to access an backend web server on a virtual machine running Gitorious. I have looked at examples and tried them but I still can't figure it out.

the goal is to forward the user when server.mysite.net/gitorious is accessed to the back end virtual server.

I have added the following to my config file but I get an error saying "invalid command ProxyPreserveHost" when I restart apache.

```
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass /gitorious http://192.168.1.168
ProxyPassReverse /gitorious http://192.168.1.168
```

Comment: There doesnt seem to be anything wrong with your config. Maybe a dumb question, but which version of apache are you running?

Comment: I'm running Apache2 on ubuntu 12.04.1LTS

Answer (score 1):

Do you have enabled proxy module in Apache?

```
a2enmod proxy
```

Comment: That might be the reason. I'll try it when I get home. Thank you.